# MVC 5 project not working anymore after installing SQL Server 2012 express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 4. I Created a default MVC5 ASP.NET web application, tested, run, everything OK. I selected Individual account authorization (default), and no change whatsoever.

I tried then to publish locally on the same PC's IIS server, but I had problems connecting to the database.

I installed SQL Server 2012 Express, and since then, nothing works anymore.
The error I got is [(exactly as here)](http://forums.asp.net/t/2010163.aspx?Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+Microsoft+Owin+Version+2+1+0+0+Culture+neutral+PublicKeyToken+31bf3856ad364e35+or+one+of+its+dependencies+The+located+assembly+s+manifest+definition+does+not+match+the+assembly+reference+Exception+from+HRESULT+) :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
```

Trying to solve the problem by installing the 2.1.0 nuget packages seems to partially fix the problem, because later in the application run I get an error about webgrease, but here is no version mismatch.

Is it possible that the project takes the web.config from some other place? How to fix this issue? I don't want to run with owin 2.1.0 since the latest version is 3.0.1. And why it doesn't work after installing SQL? Uninstalling SQL and reinstalling Visual Studio doesn't fix the problem.

Here is the web.config snippet (not working):

```
...
<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
...
```

Here is the package log from the machine with Sql Server 2012 express (NOT WORKING:

```
PM> Get-Package

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                     
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                     
Antlr                          3.4.1.9004           ANother Tool for Language Recognition, is a language tool that provides a framework for con...
bootstrap                      3.0.0                Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.     
EntityFramework                6.1.1                Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.      
jQuery                         1.10.2               jQuery is a new kind of JavaScript Library....                                                
jQuery.Validation              1.11.1               This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation trivial, while offering lots of ...
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0                Core interfaces for ASP.NET Identity.                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.E... 2.1.0                ASP.NET Identity providers that use Entity Framework.                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 2.1.0                Owin implementation for ASP.NET Identity.                                                     
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc           5.2.2                This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC gives you a power...
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor         3.2.2                This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web Pages. ASP.NET Web Pages and t...
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi... 1.1.3                ASP.NET Optimization introduces a way to bundle and optimize CSS and JavaScript files.        
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages      3.2.2                This package contains core runtime assemblies shared between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Pa...
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusiv... 3.2.2                jQuery plugin that unobtrusively sets up jQuery.Validation.                                   
Microsoft.Owin                 3.0.0                Provides a set of helper types and abstractions for simplifying the creation of OWIN compon...
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb  3.0.0                OWIN server that enables OWIN-based applications to run on IIS using the ASP.NET request pi...
Microsoft.Owin.Security        3.0.0                Common types which are shared by the various authentication middleware components.            
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Coo... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to use cookie based authentication, similar to ASP.N...
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Fac... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support Facebook's OAuth 2.0 authentication workf...
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google 3.0.0                Contains middlewares to support Google's OpenId and OAuth 2.0 authentication workflows.       
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Mic... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support the Microsoft Account authentication work...
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth  3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support any standard OAuth 2.0 authentication wor...
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twi... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support Twitter's OAuth 2.0 authentication workflow.
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure   1.0.0.0              This package contains the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure assembly that lets you dynamically r...
Modernizr                      2.6.2                Modernizr adds classes to the <html> element which allow you to target specific browser fun...
Newtonsoft.Json                6.0.4                Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET                                
Owin                           1.0                  OWIN IAppBuilder startup interface                                                            
Respond                        1.2.0                The goal of this script is to provide a fast and lightweight (3kb minified / 1kb gzipped) s...
WebGrease                      1.5.2                Web Grease is a suite of tools for optimizing javascript, css files and images.
```

Here is the package log from a different machine, without SQL Server, working:

PM> Get-Package

```
Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                        
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                        
Antlr                          3.4.1.9004           ANother Tool for Language Recognition, is a language tool that provides a framework for constr...
bootstrap                      3.0.0                Sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.        
EntityFramework                6.1.1                Entity Framework is Microsoft's recommended data access technology for new applications.         
jQuery                         1.10.2               jQuery is a new kind of JavaScript Library....                                                   
jQuery.Validation              1.11.1               This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation trivial, while offering lots of opt...
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0                Core interfaces for ASP.NET Identity.                                                            
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.E... 2.1.0                ASP.NET Identity providers that use Entity Framework.                                            
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 2.1.0                Owin implementation for ASP.NET Identity.                                                        
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc           5.2.2                This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful...
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor         3.2.2                This package contains the runtime assemblies for ASP.NET Web Pages. ASP.NET Web Pages and the ...
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi... 1.1.3                ASP.NET Optimization introduces a way to bundle and optimize CSS and JavaScript files.           
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages      3.2.2                This package contains core runtime assemblies shared between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Pages.  
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusiv... 3.2.2                jQuery plugin that unobtrusively sets up jQuery.Validation.                                      
Microsoft.Owin                 3.0.0                Provides a set of helper types and abstractions for simplifying the creation of OWIN components. 
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb  3.0.0                OWIN server that enables OWIN-based applications to run on IIS using the ASP.NET request pipel...
Microsoft.Owin.Security        3.0.0                Common types which are shared by the various authentication middleware components.               
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Coo... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to use cookie based authentication, similar to ASP.NET'...
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Fac... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support Facebook's OAuth 2.0 authentication workflow.  
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google 3.0.0                Contains middlewares to support Google's OpenId and OAuth 2.0 authentication workflows.          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Mic... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support the Microsoft Account authentication workflow. 
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth  3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support any standard OAuth 2.0 authentication workflow.
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twi... 3.0.0                Middleware that enables an application to support Twitter's OAuth 2.0 authentication workflow.   
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure   1.0.0.0              This package contains the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure assembly that lets you dynamically regi...
Modernizr                      2.6.2                Modernizr adds classes to the <html> element which allow you to target specific browser functi...
Newtonsoft.Json                6.0.4                Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET                                   
Owin                           1.0                  OWIN IAppBuilder startup interface                                                               
Respond                        1.2.0                The goal of this script is to provide a fast and lightweight (3kb minified / 1kb gzipped) scri...
WebGrease                      1.5.2                Web Grease is a suite of tools for optimizing javascript, css files and images.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with SQL Server. Do a search in your web.config for Microsoft.Owin and see if there are any references to it.

Comment: I attached the web.config to the problem description. I changed nothing in the project. I created the project, run, everything was ok, install SQL Server ... nothing works anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such problems before. The correct installation order is SQL Server 2012 `THEN` Visual Studio 2013.

This is because SQL Server is already built using some Visual Studio components, which override Visual Studio 2013 components causing incorrect behavior/problems.

Same thing for Visual Studio 2010, 2008 and SQL Server 2008. SQL Server should be always the first.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem, BUT ONLY if I manually uninstall all SQL-related components left after uninstalling Visual Studio, including SSDT.